# Where can I post this type of question? (Smart boards tutorial)

Tags: support, site-recommendation

This is the content of the question that I would like to post. Where do you think I can ask a question like?

> I have been trying to find a good resource to teach me how to develop applications for smart boards using C#. Is there a good resource that I can use? I have downloaded the Smart SDK from http://smarttech.com , and in the sample files there is a visual studio project that has a bunch of code that I can't seem to understand. At the moment I do not have the smart board hardware, so testing the sample is nearly impossible. I really apologise for such a silly question, but when I google for tutorials I get a bunch of results that help teachers use the software and not how to actually develop the software. Do any of you have any links or suggestions that can point me in the right direction? I am really lost with this at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere that isn't a Stack Exchange site.

Seriously.

This is a question asking for an external resource, which is not something suitable for pretty much all Stack Exchange sites.

Answers tend to be both opinionated and not backed by an actual comparison of all options. They also date. badly.

These go against our goals for questions and answers - where we want to be able to point at an answer as **the** right answer, where answers are backed up by more than anecdotal evidence and where answers can live long and prosper.